# How to convert audio files from mp4 to mp3 using applescript?

Tags: ffmpeg, applescript

Can someone please help me understand how to convert audio files from mp4 to mp3 using AppleScript?

I have tried scripting VLC or Sound Studio but the commands don't seem to come close to doing that. I downloaded and installed ffmpeg but I don't know the syntax to use.

I tried something like this with ffmpeg:

```
 tell application "Finder"
set CurrentPath to container of (path to me) as alias
set OriginalFile to CurrentPath & "ASProcessing:SoundToProcess.mp4" as string
set NewFile to CurrentPath & "ASProcessing:NewFile.mp3" as string

end tell


 set outputFile to POSIX path of OriginalFile
 set inputFile to POSIX path of NewFile
 do shell script ffmpeg something, something
```

But clearly I'm missing most of the script syntax. Eventually, I would do a repeat loop to go through a set of files.

Sorry that I can't be more specific. I'm pretty lost with this. What I do know is that I do not want to use Automator. I need something like AppleScript.

Thanks.

mbust

Comment: Since `ffmpeg` runs in a `shell`, why not just do it in a `bash` _script_ without using AppleScript? For the proper syntax of `ffmpeg`, read its man page. The basic syntax is `ffmpeg -i filename.mp4 filename.mp3` but I'd suggest you use Google, i.e. `ffmpeg mp4 to mp3` and do some reading.

Comment: Because not just me, but even more so the final user, does not know how to do bash scripts, so I would want to wrap it in an AppleScript app. Thanks for responding.

Comment: Have you tried looking into using *QuickTime Player* ?  That *might* be able to do it.  But I agree with @user3439894 that *ffmpeg* is probably the way to go, which you can wrap in an AppleScript app by calling a `do shell script` command (which can be as simple as: `do shell script "ffmpeg -i filename.mp4 filename.mp3"`).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I prefer the wrapping the shell script within AppleScript, and I'm grateful for the suggested syntax. At the end, because the end user was going to be relying on a FileMaker database to handle the sound files, I used a plugin (MediaManager) that works really well.